# How to display products from subcategories in parent categories in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
def category(request, id):
    
    category_user = Category.objects.filter(pk=id).prefetch_related(
    'children__product_set',
    ).get()

    products=Product.objects.filter(category__in=category_user.children.all())
    
    context = {'category_user':category_user, 'products': products}

    return render(request, 'store/category.html', context)
```

Now products from different categories are separated. I want to display "children" products in main category too, but I don't know how. Pls help. Thank u in advance.

Comment: In your template, try with `{% for child_category in category_user.children.all %}`

Comment: but I want to display products not categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the products of all the child categories (your "children" products) in your template like this:

```
{% for child_category in category_user.children.all %}
    {% for child_product in child_category.product_set.all %}
        {{ child_product }}
    {$ endfor}
{% endfor %}
```

You will also want to optimise your query to build the children products using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
category_user = Category.objects.filter(pk=id).prefetch_related(
    'children__product_set',
).get()
```

to avoid hitting the DB per child category.

Comment: It works, but can you do the same in views.py? I need to have all products in one variable "products", so that paginate and sort them.

Comment: You need to share your other models for that. And if this answer helped you at all please do consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027465) it

Comment: Anyway try this: `Product.objects.filter(category__in=category_user.children.all())`. Since you haven't shared your models, this might fail but you get the idea ;)

Comment: I've just accepted your answer, added product model and tried your solution from last comment, but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: No errors, just the same problem as at the beginning

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: I've only changed views.py

Comment: Shouldn't you add another object for the child products? So something like: `products = Product.objects.filter(category=category_user)` for the main products, and another with:
`child_products = Product.objects.filter(category__in=category_user.children.all())` for the child category products

Comment: And then pass both in the template, then render them separately?

Comment: And how will I be able to sum them up to one variable later?

Comment: But I want to use pagination and sorting, so I have to have it in one var, that is the problem :c

Comment: I see. Then you can use union to combine them: `all_products = products.union(child_products)`

Comment: No worries. Have fun!

Comment: Have a nice coffee :)